# gtk_css_value_inherit_free: code should not be reached

Tags: python-3.x, plugins, gtk3, rhythmbox

I making one plugin with Python for Rhythmbox.

I get an **randomly error** when start the plugin. Then of some seconds I reset Rhythmbox and the plugin run ok.

What will the cases that probably originy the error?

**Error:**

```
gtkcssinheritvalue.c:33:gtk_css_value_inherit_free: code should not be reached
```

**gtkcssinheritvalue.c:**

```
29  static void
30  gtk_css_value_inherit_free (GtkCssValue *value)
31  {
32    /* Can only happen if the unique value gets unreffed too often */
33    g_assert_not_reached ();
34  }
```

https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/gtk-3-6/gtk/gtkcssinheritvalue.c

All suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same error. For my case, it seems to be related to labels

Comment: You might get more information by debugging: `gdb -ex r --args python3 script.py`. For me it's caused by `gtk_widget_create_pango_layout`